# Thinning or skeletonization with java

Tags: java

How to thin or skeletonization the image with java?
I mean I want to get the skeleton of the character image, and this need to implement with java for the OCR process. Thanks for your interest and give me some suggestion and direction.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is a Java problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get you right, if is about edge detection in images.
Check this tutorial [Image Processing and Enhancement](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/2d/spec/j2d-image.fm8.html)

Comment: Skeletonization is literally finding the paths not edges within an image. Its not about edge detection but rather finding the skeleton that holds up the structure of the black part of an image.